# Control attachments menu order with jQuery Sortable

Tags: attachments, ajax, media-library, sort, jquery-ui

I've managed create a metabox that lets me upload and then fetch the images and then also been able to add jquery ui sortable to be able to sort the images, however I've no idea how to add actual functionality so that the sort order get saved.

If someone has an idea how to achieve this or some tutorial that would be helpful, please share, I'm helplessly stuck here.

Thanks.

Edit:
Basically, what I need to know is how to tie jQuery sortable together with the functionality that handles the different attachments menu_order.

Comment: _Note: I don't know what exactly you use to upload images from your meta box, but I guess you did stick with that most reknown tutorials and enritched your metabox custom field to use the media uploader. If the below answer doesn't fit, than you've been too less specific in your Q and didn't put in enough effort to let us know what we're dealing with. In this case, please go back and update your Q._

Comment: @kaiser Sorry for being a bit vague in my question. I've updated the Q with some more information. I'm not using the regular media uploader. I'm using Uploadify that ties in with the media library, though it works exactly the same as it would with the regular media uploader. So what I need is someway to use the menu order that I create with jQuery Sortable (check this video: http://youtu.be/zvPnem6ady4) and then save it as a menu_order ID for my different attachments. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Line 1228 in media.php in wp-admin/includes seems to have the functionality for how sorting natively in WP works. Not sure how to make use of it though..

Comment: The answer below shows you how to sort in your tempaltes after you got around this one. Sorry, but I ain't have the time now to solve your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the menu order use `wp_update_post()` with each attachment ID and its new menu position:

```
$thisattachment = array();
$thisattachment['ID'] = $thisid;
$thisattachment['menu_order'] = $new_menu_position;
wp_update_post($thisattachment);
```

EDIT - assuming these are already attachments and you're updating them? Otherwise you have to insert the attachments first with [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

Comment: This seems to be what I want, will try as soon as I get a chance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within the WordPress admin you should be able to order the attached media associated with a post/page/custom once it's been uploaded using the Gallery Tab. This will then effect the order in which they get called from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this, but I'm wondering how I might hook into this and make use of it for my custom image/attachment handler. Here's a video: http://youtu.be/zvPnem6ady4 When I've moved the images around, I want the order to be saved.

Comment: You could set a hidden field up that is updated with jquery then stored as the order.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to get post attachments

If you're on a single post view, you'll have the `global $post` available. If you then want to have all attachments, place the following in your code:

```
$attachments = array_values( get_children( array( 
     'post_parent'      => $post->post_parent
    ,'post_status'      => 'inherit'
    ,'post_type'        => 'attachment'
    ,'post_mime_type'   => 'image'
    ,'order'            => 'ASC'
    ,'orderby'          => 'menu_order ID' 
) ) );
```

`'menu_order ID'` means that you order by `'menu_order'` *AND* `'ID'`.

#### How to sort post attachments

*Note: Your attachments are object, close to normal posts. They got an `'ID'`, got `'menu_order'` like pages, etc.*

In some special cases, ordering won't work, so you can use a callback function, to trigger ordering by the ID:

```
usort( $attachments, 'sort_cb' );
```

Then the function to compare and sort.

```
function sort( $a, $b )
{
    if ( $a->menu_order == $b->menu_order )
        return null;

    return ( $a->menu_order > $b->menu_order ) ? +1 : -1;
}
```